# Consolidate Facebook Log In permissions into one popup

Tags: facebook, authentication, permissions, popup

Our Facebook app requests the following permissions:

- user_website
- email
- manage_pages
- publish_stream
- read_insights

When we use the Facebook "Log In" button (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/), three distinct popups are consecutively displayed (one after another - you must click "Okay" each time):

[image: Popup 1]
[image: Popup 2]
[image: Popup 3]

My guess is that these popups deliberately separate out and group the permissions by similarity/type.  However, for our (non-tech savvy) users, this is an awkward and confusing use case.  Facebook used to consolidate all of these permissions into one screen.

Is there a way to consolidate them into one screen with the current implementation of the FB "Log In" button?

Comment: This is deliberate, read and write permissions are separated (though i'm not sure why there's a third page, maybe the extended permissions still trigger the third page, i thought they were rolled into page two though) - you're not supposed to be asking for read and write at the same time anyway